# PHP ssh2_exec answering to prompt questions

Tags: php, openvpn

I must use ssh2_exec to install some packages on linux servers. Some of the packages require some answers when installing so I must be able to provide those answers using the ssh2_exec function from PHP. I already know the answers to those questions but it's hard to enter the response when the question is prompted. Example:

```
//        Build command for OpenVPN
ssh2_exec ( $connection, "./build-ca" );
```

The above command will trigger openvpn to be configured so it asks a few questions such as:

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [US]:
```

For the above question I must answer "US" and hit enter to continue etc. Any ideas how to do this using ssh2_exec function?

Comment: Total shot in the dark - I've never used this function - but how about `ssh2_exec ( $connection, "./build-ca < us" );`?

Comment: Well....the command prompts for more than one answer....8 actually...How will I solve all of them?

Anyways...that command gives an error: -bash: US: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

The only clean solution is not executing programs expecting user input. Check if build.ca has a config file where you can give default values and if yes, upload a such a file via SCP and then execute build-ca so it uses these values.

Comment: Yeah I've done that but it still asks. The US part of the question above is already entered by me in the config file.